# Overriding ModelState's very technical error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding, modelstate

I have the following code:

```
public class EventController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(List<Event> Events)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Event Event in Events)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(Event.Importance.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine(Event.Date.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine(Event.Description);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}

public class Event
{
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Integer(ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a number.")]
    [Range(0,10),Required()]        
    public int? Importance { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^.{20,100}$", ErrorMessage="{0} must be between 20 and 100 characters.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm posting the following JSON:

```
[{"Importance":"1.1","Date":"2015-03-12","Description":""},{"Importance":"6","Date":"2015-10-02","Description":"a"}]
```

The response is:

```
{
"Message": "The request is invalid.",
"ModelState": {
"Events[0].Importance": [
"Could not convert string to integer: 1.1. Path '[0].Importance', line 1, position 20.",
  "The Importance field is required."
],
"Events[1].Description": [
  "Description must be between 20 and 100 characters."
]
```

}
    }

I'm concerned about "Could not convert string to integer: 1.1. Path '[0].Importance', line 1, position 20."
I'd like to override this message with something more friendly and less revealing, perhaps "Importance must be a number.". Ideally I'd like to define the default conversion error in a DataAnnotation. I tried using the DataAnnotationsExtensions Nuget found here http://dataannotationsextensions.org/ unfortunately this targets MVC and does not override the ModelState errors. If this isn't possible to override, I'm curious what the common workarounds might be.

Answer (score 2):

One solution (what I don't like a lot) would be use object type instead of int? type:

```
public class Event
{
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Integer(ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a number.")]
    [Range(0,10),Required()]        
    public object Importance { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

If you do that then the conversion default message will be overridden.